Adding a new UART sensor to the kernel device tree
I have an out-of-tree sensor that communicates over a UART with my STM32MP13. I am writing its kernel module and I want to include the sensor so that it is directly recognized by the kernel.
The sensor is attached to UART8 so I thought that the sensor node should be a child node of the UART8 node. When building my image with Yocto I get an error when compiling the DTS. Any documentation or guidelines in this context are much appreciated.
&uart8 {
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep", "idle";
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart8_pins_a>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&uart8_sleep_pins_a>;
    pinctrl-2 = <&uart8_idle_pins_a>;
    /delete-property/dmas;
    /delete-property/dma-names;
    status = "okay";
    sensor: sensor@0 {
        compatible = "vendor,sensor";
        status = "okay"
        current-speed = <115200>;
    }
};


So i resolved this problem. What i was doing is assigning a non-declared property to my sensor "current-speed" which belongs to the uart8 node. By declaring "current-speed" under uart8 node everything went okay.

In your question, you wrote that you got an error when compiling the DTS, but surely the check for the "current-speed" property (or lack thereof) is done at kernel run-time?
